# Java TCP IP server client readline for TOF simulator

Tags: java, tcplistener, reuters

I try to write an application read and send data to Reuters TOF simulator.

I send a message to TOF server with file seperator (FS ASCII(28)) like here

```
 package tr.com.calikbank.bnspr.treasury.reutersClient;
```

`import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static final String FS = Character.toString((char) 28);
    public static final String US = Character.toString((char) 31);
    public static final String GS = Character.toString((char) 29);

    private static DataInputStream in;
    private static Socket sock;
    private static DataOutputStream out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
            IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        sock = new Socket("10.90.20.76", 5003);
        sock.setKeepAlive(true);

        in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

        String message = FS + "333" + US + "AE" + GS + "AAAA#1" + FS;

        out.flush();
        out.writeBytes(message);
        out.flush();

        // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
        // InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        // line = reader.readLine();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
            if (line.isEmpty())
                break;

        }
        // line = in.readLine();
        // sb.append(line).append("\n");

        System.out.println("Message received from the server : "
                + sb.toString());

    }

}`

<>

but the program stuck in while loop and when I stop server then return whole string but I need get without stop server. whats the problem.

my decision is readline has a problem with reference sth 5530xD0xA

thnx

Comment: server response like that <FS>340<US>AE<GS>AAAA#3<US>501<US>0
<RS>553<US>0xD0xA
<RS>500<US>3
<RS>501<US>1728
<RS>539<US> 
<RS>540<US>6
<RS>502<US>19 MAR 2015
<RS>503<US>15:58:27
<RS>504<US>SC
<RS>505<US>16 NOV 2016
<RS>506<US> 7:15:08
<RS>507<US>SC
<RS>508<US>TURK
<RS>509<US>BANK YZ LONDON
<RS>510<US> 
<RS>511<US> 
<RS>513<US> 
<RS>514<US>1
<RS>569<US>2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package tr.com.calikbank.bnspr.treasury.reutersClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static final String FS = Character.toString((char) 28);
    public static final String US = Character.toString((char) 31);
    public static final String GS = Character.toString((char) 29);
    public static final String RS = Character.toString((char) 30);

    private static DataInputStream in;
    private static Socket sock;
    private static DataOutputStream out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
            IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5003);
        sock.setKeepAlive(true);

        in = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

        String message = FS + "333" + US + "AE" + GS + "AAAA#1" + FS;
          //String message=FS+"332"+US+"XX"+GS+"AAAA#INFO"+FS;

        out.flush();
        out.writeBytes(message);
        out.flush();

        // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
        // InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int i=0;
        // line = reader.readLine();
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] inputData = new byte[5000];
            in.read(inputData);

            sb.append(new String(inputData));
            i++;
            if (i==3)
                break;

        }
        // line = in.readLine();
        // sb.append(line).append("\n");

        System.out.println("Message received from the server : "
                + sb.toString());

        String temps=new String(sb.toString());
        String temps2=new String(sb.toString());

        String[] partsUS = temps.split(US);

        for (int j=0;i<partsUS.length;i++)
        System.out.println(partsUS[i]); // 340


        String[] partsRS = temps2.split(RS);

        System.out.println("-----------");

        for (int j=0;j<partsRS.length;j++)
            System.out.println(partsRS[j]); // 340





    }

}
```

Comment: now I happily run the code. I hope this sample code helps the other integration developers.